# How to force Odata to work with my custom DTO object?

Tags: c#, odata

I want to use OData with my DTO objects, but my DTO object properties not names exactly as entities.

Moreover the structure is different - as shown here:

My entities:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity<TKey>
{
    public virtual TKey Id { get; set; }
}

public class ContentTranslation : BaseEntity<int>
{
    public int ContentId { get; set; }
    public Content Content { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Language Language { get; set; }
}

public class Content : BaseEntity<int>
{
    public ContentType ContentType { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ContentTranslation> Translations { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }
    public FAQ Faq { get; set; }
    public Announcement Announcement { get; set; }
}

public class FAQ : BaseEntity<int>
{
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public int ContentId { get; set; }
    public Content Content { get; set; }
}

public class Announcement : BaseEntity<int>
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public DateTime ValiUntil { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Content")]
    public int ContentId { get; set; }
    public Content Content { get; set; }
}
```

My DTOs:

```
public class AnnouncementModel
{
    public int ContentId { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public State State { get; set; }
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public DateTime ValiUntil { get; set; }
}

public class ContentDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public JObject Content { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<Language,TranslationDTO> Translations { get; set; }
}

public class FaqModel
{
    public int ContentId { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public State State { get; set; }
    public string MainTag { get; set; }
}
```

Language, State are enums

```
public enum ContentType
{
    FAQ,
    Announcement
}

public enum Language
{
    UA,
    EN
}

public enum State
{
    Modified,
    Published,
    Deleted
}
```

In JObject I want to place concrete type of content (FAQ or Announcement)

So my question is how to create a custom mapping that will map my DTOs to entities.

Actually I think that OData use some method to convert from EDMModel to entities.
So can I place my custom mapping as a middle between EDMModel and the entities?

If so, will it work with all functions in url query like $select and $expand.
To each method of OData I can add my custom mapper to enable all OData functionality to work with DTO.

Comment: Think OData as a frontend to expose the data you want to publish, a frontend that executes queries. So you have the OData entities and your DTO entities. You should connect (map) the data without executing the query. You could check [Automapper IQueryable extensions](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html)

Comment: @bradbury9  Will Automapper work with such object as JObject and Dicltionary<enum, object>? And my queries will be executed on Entities not Dtos?

Comment: Well, I would suggest you trying automapper, doing so testing and checking if it fits your needs

Comment: @bradbury9y can you explain please how it works? If I place this automapper between Entity and Dto , than in my presentation lier I will be able to work with Dto as entities. Or it (automapper) has a complex structure that map all DTO model properties on ODAta model and than on Entity, Or OData->DTO->(Automapper)->entity.

Comment: Automapper can translate the queries from one type to the other without executing them, it only returns an `IQueryable` object, so the OData query is translated into the type used in your data source and the OData API executes the translated query. I dont know how automapper does works internally